# Getting multiple row ID's without loop

Tags: php

The values I have are in a session. I can't use JOIN (I assume) because that is for multiple tables. I'm working with one table.

The table is called 'VEHICLES'. Each row has a field called 'car' and has an AUTO INCREMENTED ID. I need the ID for each $car*. So I would like a query that will pull ID's only if $car* exists.

There will always be at least one $car*. But 2, 3, 4 cars etc... are possible. How can check for, and query these possibly existing $cars?

```
$car1 = 'Honda';
$car2 = 'Mazda';
$car3 = '';

$query="SELECT
  id( WHERE car='$car1') as My_car1,
  id( WHERE car='$car2') as My_car2,
FROM VEHICLES";

list($My_car1,$My_car2)=pdo_fetch_array(pdo_query($query));
```

I realize my query is wrong and will not work. But it was the only way I could visually explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: You shouldn't use `$car1, $car2` but an array like `$car[1], $car[2]`. That would make the solution suggested easier to implement.

Comment: Much appreciated reply, Anthony. How do I make the possible results an array?

Comment: Simply refactor the code so that `$car1 = 'Honda';` is replaced with `$car[1] = 'Honda'`. You could then use an `implode()` to have the array transformed into a comma-separated string that could be used in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Basic SQL:

```
SELECT id
FROM VEHICLES
WHERE car IN ('Honda', 'Mazda')
```

And as a general tip, **NEVER** chain DB calls the way you are. DB operations can/will fail, and you're assuming success. if any of the "inner" calls fail, they'll return a boolean false and break the outer calls. You'll be left in the dark as to why things failed.

**NEVER** assume success when dealing with external resources. Always assume everything will fail, CHECK for failure at every stage, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Thank you, Marc. I will read up on your suggestions as I am a beginner and really do not understand what chain DB means. On a side note, I can't see how to check for existing $car with the query suggested.